# Server and connection limits for long poll in ASP.NET MVC 1 in .NET 3.5 SP1 using asynchronous controllers from MVC Futures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asynchronous, comet, long-polling

**I'm trying to retro-fit a long poll ("reverse ajax", "http push") feature into an existing ASP.NET MVC 1 web application running on .NET 3.5 SP1**. Since this applications has thousands of concurrent users, and all of them will use the long poll feature, **I'm worried that I will run into server and connection limits which are hard to fore-see and test.**

Having read [Thomas Marquardt's article on ASP.NET Thread Usage on IIS 7.0 and 6.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx), which is referenced in many questions about long polling here and elsewhere, it *seems* that *the **default** settings for a Windows Server 2008 R2 (with IIS 7.5) running an ASP.NET MVC 1 application (in .NET 3.5 SP1) where the long poll feature is implemented using asynchronous controllers from MVC Futures will **not** be able to serve thousands of users.*

**The first culprit seems to be `maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU`, which in .NET 3.5 SP1 is set to 12** according to Marquardt. This means thousands of concurrent long polls would require hundreds of CPUs, right? Since whether or not using asynchronous controllers, a long poll is still an HTTP request. I'd need to increase this. **Is my understanding here correct?**

Since I'm using asynchronous controllers, I'm assuming I won't need to alter the number of concurrent worker threads per CPU, since the thread waiting for the long poll to trigger will be unwound. **Is my understanding here correct?** Or does this vary with how exactly the "waiting" in the long poll action method is accomplished? (I was planning on using events.)

In addition to this, are there other limitations I will run into? I don't want to start randomly increasing values in `machine.config` or `aspnet.config` (or even `web.config`), and I'd like to keep the `autoConfig` of the `processModel`, if possible.

(I've read all the questions here, but none specifically dig into details regarding this, presumably since it varies with number of CPUs, CLR version, etc.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIS wasn't built with long-running concurrent requests in mind and just doesn't scale. You might want to look at Frozen Mountain's [Web Sync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/) component, at [XSockets](http://xsockets.net/), which is a WebSocket server with fallback support or at outsourcing your realtime functionality to a [dedicated hosted realtime service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-technologies-guide#hosted-services).

Comment: @leggetter, IIS doesn't scale? I think a citation is lacking here. :)

Comment: @bzlm I'm not saying IIS doesn't scale at all. I'm saying that long-running concurrent requests don't scale all that well. IIS wasn't build with that in mind. Other server technologies have been build from the ground up to meet this need and offer a much better solution. As a standard web server IIS is fine but you wouldn't generally use it as a static file server when there are better solutions available. So, I wouldn't use it as a realtime server when there **are** better solutions available.

Comment: You should take a look at SignalR (http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SignalR). Hanselman just blogged about it: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: SignalR uses long polling (so same difference) and also the dynamic runtime, which means an ASP.NET 3.5 app is out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're misunderstanding the point of Asynchronous Controllers.  Async controllers are used for long-running web calls (note: **not** long polling calls).  Meaning that if an action takes time to process/return, it will be processed asynchronously, returning control to the client immediately.

If you want to implement long polling, use SignalR

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx